# Delphi: Using function from main class in a subclass

Tags: delphi

On the new side of writing classes and have a little problem which I have tried researching but still no answer.

I want to create one instance of a class which creates multiple subclasses which creates subclasses of their own. The idea is to use code like this in main program:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Temp : Integer;
begin
  MainClass := TMainClass.Create(Form1);
  Temp := MainClass.SubClass1.SubSubClass1.SomeValue;
end;
```

The main class looks like this and is created in seperate file:

```
  TMainClass = class(TObject)
    private
      FSubClass1 : TSubClass1;
    public
      ValueFromAnySubClass : Integer;
      property SubClass1 : TSubClass1 read FSubClass1 write FSubClass1;
      procedure SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value : Integer);
  end;
...
...
...
procedure TMainClass.SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value : Integer);
begin
  ValueFromAnySubClass := Value;
end;
```

The sub class also in seperate file:

```
  TSubClass1 = class(TObject)
    private
      FSubSubClass1 : TSubSubClass1;
    public
      property SubSubClass1 : TSubSubClass1 read FSubSubClass1 write FSubSubClass1;
  end;
```

And now for the sub sub class also in seperate file:

```
  TSubSubClass1 = class(TObject)
  private
    SomeValue : Integer;
    function  GetSomeValue : Integer;
    procedure SetSomeValue(Value : Integer);
  public
    property SomeValue : Integer read GetSomeValue write SetSomeValue;
  end;
...
...
...
procedure TSubSubClass1.SetSomeValue(Value : Integer);
begin
  SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value); <<< Error Here <<<
end;
```

How do I get to use the functions and procedures from the main class in my sub classes?

Comment: It looks to me like you're misunderstanding the concept of a "sub-class". A subclass inherits from a parent. Nothing in your code shows any inheritance.

Comment: @CraigYoung: Correct. To Cybotage: These are contained classes, i.e. the outer class contains the inner class, etc., just like a TForm-derived class can contain a TEdit or a TButton. They are most definitely not subclasses.

Comment: Just a terminology mix-up.

Comment: For lack of a better term I used the wrong one, my apologies. As for design I cant give out any more details unfortunately. I know its not the best but its better than what is currently implemented in the project that I took over. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a subclass to use a function from another class. Also your sample code has not used subclasses at all. A *proper* subclass automatically has access to all public and proteced functions of its ancestors.

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389660/224704) has already pointed out, there are serious flaws in your intended deisgn.

Furthermore, based on your comment:

> The classes all perform vastly different functions but need to write data to a piece of hardware at the end of the day. The data is read from the hardware and kept in memory to work with until its written back to the hardware component once all work is completed. The procedure in the main class takes care of writing real time data to the hardware whenever it is required by any of the subclasses.

to David's answer: you don't need subclasses at all.

All you need is a public method on your hardware class. And for each instance of your other classes to have a reference to the correct instance of your hardware class.

```
type
  THardwareDevice = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure WriteData(...);
  end;

  TOtherClass1 = class(TObject)
  private
    FDevice: THardwareDevice;
  public
    constructor Create(ADevice: THardwareDevice);

    procedure DoSomething;
  end;


constructor TOtherClass1.Create(ADevice: THardwareDevice);
begin
  FDevice := ADevice;
end;

procedure TOtherClass1.DoSomething;
begin
  //Do stuff, and maybe you need to tell the hardware to write data
  FDevice.WriteData(...);
end;

//Now given the above you can get two distinct object instances to interact
//as follows. The idea can be extended to more "other class" types and instances.
begin
  FPrimaryDevice := THardwareDevice.Create(...);
  FObject1 := TOtherClass1.Create(FPrimaryDevice);
  FObject1.DoSomething;

  //NOTE: This approach allows extreme flexibility because you can easily
  //      reference different instances (objects) of the same hardware class.
  FBackupDevice := THardwareDevice.Create(...);
  FObject2 := TOtherClass1.Create(FBackupDevice);
  FObject2.DoSomething;

  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

The design looks really poor. You surely don't want to have all these classes knowing all about each other.

And any time you see a line of code with more than one `.` operator you should ask yourself if the code is in the right class. Usually that indicates that the line of code that has multiple uses of `.` should be in one of the classes further down the chain.

However, if you want to call a method, you need an instance. You write:

```
procedure TSubSubClass1.SetSomeValue(Value : Integer);
begin
  SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value);
end;
```

And naturally this does not compile. Because `SetSomeValueFromMainClass` is not a method of `TSubSubClass1`. Rather `SetSomeValueFromMainClass` is a method of `TMainClass`. So, to call that method, you need an instance of `TMainClass`.

Which suggests that, if you really must do this, that you need to supply to each instance of `TSubSubClass1` an instance of `TMainClass`. You might supply that in the constructor and make a note of the reference.

Of course, when you do this you now find that your classes are all coupled together with each other. At which point one might wonder whether or not they should be merged.

I'm not saying that merging these classes is the right design. I would not like to make any confident statement as to what the right design is. Perhaps what you need is an interface that promises to implement the setter as a means to decouple things. All I am really confident in saying is that your current design is not the right design.

Comment: The design might look poor from the example I have given but it's actually not that poor. The classes all perform vastly different functions but need to write data to a piece of hardware at the end of the day. The data is read from the hardware and kept in memory to work with until its written back to the hardware component once all work is completed. The procedure in the main class takes care of writing real time data to the hardware whenever it is required by any of the subclasses.

Comment: @Cybotage You might not think your design is poor, but it's actually extremely poor. The fact that you've described your problem in highly abstract concepts makes it impossible to suggest a better design. However your comment suggests each of these other classes need access to the "hardware class". To be more precise, an **instance of** the hardware class. So as David suggests, a definite consideration is that each of your other classes should be told which harware **object** to use when they're created.

Comment: These are not "sub-classes". Your describing them as such doesn't make them so. They're just independent classes that you seem intent on coupling together for whatever reason. Unfortunately, your description in the abstract using inappropriate names is not going to get anybody anywhere other than a debate, which is exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Subclass word is usually using in inheritance concept but the code you wrote are some compound classes. As you may see the constructor of many classes in Delphi have an argument which named AOwner that may be TComponent or TObject or ...

If you define  the constructors of your TSubclass1 and TSubSubClass1 like as follow and Change the Owner of classes that you defined as properties to Self in set functions you may access to your TMainClass by typecasting the Owner property.

I changed your code a little to just work as you want, but I suggest change your design.

```
  TSubSubClass1 = class(TObject)
  private
    FOwner: TObject;
    function GetSomeValue:Integer;
    procedure SetSomeValue(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetOwner(const Value: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TObject);reintroduce;
    property Owner:TObject read FOwner write SetOwner;
    property SomeValue : Integer read GetSomeValue write SetSomeValue;
  end;

  TSubClass1 = class(TObject)
  private
    FSubSubClass1: TSubSubClass1;
    FOwner:TObject;
    procedure SetSubSubClass1(const Value: TSubSubClass1);
    procedure SetOwner(const Value: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TObject);reintroduce;
    property Owner:TObject read FOwner write SetOwner;
    property SubSubClass1 : TSubSubClass1 read FSubSubClass1 write SetSubSubClass1;
  end;

  TMainClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FSubClass1: TSubClass1;
    procedure SetSubClass1(const Value: TSubClass1);
  public
    ValueFromAnySubClass : Integer;
    constructor Create;
    property SubClass1 : TSubClass1 read FSubClass1 write SetSubClass1;
    procedure SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value : Integer);
  end;
```

implementation

```
{ TSubSubClass1 }

constructor TSubSubClass1.Create(AOwner: TObject);
begin
  Owner:=AOwner;
end;

function TSubSubClass1.GetSomeValue: Integer;
begin
  Result:=TMainClass(TSubClass1(Self.Owner).Owner).ValueFromAnySubClass;
end;

procedure TSubSubClass1.SetOwner(const Value: TObject);
begin
  FOwner := Value;
end;

procedure TSubSubClass1.SetSomeValue(const Value: Integer);
begin
  TMainClass(TSubClass1(Self.Owner).Owner).SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value);
end;

{ TSubClass1 }

constructor TSubClass1.Create(AOwner: TObject);
begin
  Owner:=AOwner;
  FSubSubClass1:=TSubSubClass1.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TSubClass1.SetOwner(const Value: TObject);
begin
  FOwner := Value;
end;

procedure TSubClass1.SetSubSubClass1(const Value: TSubSubClass1);
begin
  FSubSubClass1 := Value;
  FSubSubClass1.Owner:=Self;
end;

{ TMainClass }

constructor TMainClass.Create;
begin
  FSubClass1:=TSubClass1.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TMainClass.SetSomeValueFromMainClass(Value: Integer);
begin
  ValueFromAnySubClass := Value;
end;

procedure TMainClass.SetSubClass1(const Value: TSubClass1);
begin
  FSubClass1 := Value;
  FSubClass1.Owner:=Self;
end;
```

you must put the proper filename in uses part of implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort. I will look into this to learn and understand a bit more of classes.